Check font of first nonblank character in a line
I need to check the font of the first non-blank character on each line of a selection in Microsoft Word and if it is Courier New then do some processing on it. I have the following code but it seems inefficient. Is there a more direct way to do it please?
Dim lineRange As Range
Dim trimmedText As String
Dim i As Long

' Iterate over each paragraph in the selection range
For Each lineRange In selectionRange.Paragraphs
    ' Trim the paragraph text to remove leading and trailing spaces
    trimmedText = Trim(lineRange.Range.Text)
    
    ' Find the index of the first non-blank character
    i = 1
    Do While i <= Len(trimmedText) And Mid(trimmedText, i, 1) = " "
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    ' Check if there's at least one non-blank character in the trimmed text
    If i <= Len(trimmedText) Then
        ' Set the range to the first non-blank character
        Set lineRange = lineRange.Range.Characters(i)
        
        ' Check the font name of the first non-blank character
        If lineRange.Font.Name = "Courier New" Then
            ' Process the Courier New line here
        End If
    End If
Next lineRange



Do Loop is not necessary.
LTrim removes the leading spaces, then you can get the first non-blank char's location index
Selection is a Range object. lineRange should be declared as a Paragraph object.

For Each lineRange In selectionRange.Paragraphs

Microsoft documentation:

LTrim, RTrim, and Trim functions

Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim lineRange As Paragraph, rTarget As Range
    Dim trimmedText As String
    Dim i As Long
    ' Iterate over each paragraph in the selection range
    For Each lineRange In Selection.Paragraphs
        With lineRange.Range
            ' Trim the paragraph text to remove leading spaces
            trimmedText = LTrim(.Text)
            If Not trimmedText = vbCr Then ' Skip the blank paragraph
                i = Len(.Text) - Len(trimmedText) ' count of leading space
                ' Set the range to the first non-blank character
                Set rTarget = .Characters(i + 1)
                ' Check the font name of the first non-blank character
                If rTarget.Font.Name = "Courier New" Then
                    ' ** Process the Courier New line here
                    ' lineRange.Range.Bold = True
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next lineRange
End Sub

